# How to solve for X in Cubic poynomial

Tags: polynomials

I've been given a Polynomial (Cubic)

$$k=\frac16x\cdot(x+1)\cdot(2x+1)$$

If $k$ is given, is there any way to solve for $x$?

Comment: If $k=0$ then $x$ is one of: $0,-1,-\frac12$, for other values it's a bit more complicated

Comment: The shape (sum of squares formula) makes one guess that $x$ is an integer. If so, then $x=\left\lfloor (3k)^{1/3}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: Search for "roots of cubic polynomial". There are formulas, but they are big and ugly.

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you please elaborate

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Comment: @AndréNicolas That's a weird result, how woudl you justify it?

Comment: I am guessing you are told that the sum of the first $x$ squares is $k$ and you want to find $x$. Then from the formula, we have $2x^3\lt 6k$ and $2(x+1)^3\gt 6k$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, that does look like sum of squares, But your method doesn't always seem to work.

Comment: It is meant to work only when $x$ is a positive integers, so for $k=1,5,14,30,55$ and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solve the problem in a very special case only, where $x$ happens to be a positive integer.

Since $\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}\gt \frac{x^3}{3}$, we have $x^3\gt 3k$, and therefore $x\gt (3k)^{1/3}$.

Note that $2(x+1)^3=2x^3+6x^2+6x+2$ while $x(x+1)(2x+1)=2x^3+3x^2+x$. It follows that if $x$ is a positive integer then $\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}\lt \frac{(x+1)^3}{3}$, and therefore $x+1\gt (3k)^{1/3}$.

It follows that $x=\lfloor (3k)^{1/3}\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where $3888 k^2-1 \gt 0$,that is to say $| k| \gt \frac{1}{36 \sqrt{3}}$ and $k>0$, the only real solution is given by $$x=\frac{1}{6} \left(\sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{11664 k^2-3}+324
   k}+\frac{3^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{11664 k^2-3}+108 k}}-3\right)$$ This is Cardano formula applied to your equation.

Now, if $k$ is large, an asymptotic expansion of the solution is given by $$x=\sqrt[3]{3k} -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{k}}}{12
   \sqrt[3]{3}}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^{4/3}\right)$$ Compare to  André Nicolas's answer and comments.